# Left outer join query taking long time

Tags: sql, join, netezza

I have an SQL query that runs for a very long time. The issue is that it uses a join inside case statement. is there any way we can optimize following query:

```
Select A.Field1, A.load_date, B.field3 from A left outer join B
on (A.field_date between B.start_date and B.end_date)
AND
case 
When (A.field1=1) Then (A.field2 = B.field2 and A.field3 = B.field3)
When (A.field1=2) Then (A.field2 = B.field2)
Else (A.field3 = B.field3)
End
```

Can someone please suggest some tweak, as this query is taking hours to run. And I have to find some shorter version.

Comment: Try and split it up into 3 queries and union them together

Comment: Have you used indexes on your tables?

Comment: Can you show an EXPLAIN?

Comment: Showing some sample data testing these otherwise absurd join conditions would help, even if private data you provide "fake" values.  Not entire table structures, but legit table and column name references.  Also, it could help on why you are joining the first two conditions on field2 the same vs field3 for all other.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start:

```
 Select A.Field1, A.load_date, B.field3 
 from A 
   left outer join B
     on  (A.field_date between B.start_date and B.end_date)
     and (A.field2 = B.field2 and A.field3 = B.field3)
 where A.field1 = 1

 union all

 Select A.Field1, A.load_date, B.field3 
 from A 
   left outer join B
     on  (A.field_date between B.start_date and B.end_date)
     and (A.field2 = B.field2)
 where A.field1 = 2

 union all

 Select A.Field1, A.load_date, B.field3 
 from A 
   left outer join B
     on  (A.field_date between B.start_date and B.end_date)
     and (A.field3 = B.field3)
 where (A.field1 <> 1 and A.field1 <> 2)
```

Since your three cases are all mutually exclusive, they can be expressed as 3 separate queries that are UNION'd together.  The UNION ALL means that duplicates will not be checked for - but as no record can satisfy more than one set of criteria, there shouldn't be any.

This removes your CASE statement and allows better optimization of query paths.  No doubt others will have more suggestions.

Comment: Further to this if you explicitly filter on `A.field1` in the query selecting from this view, it might be smart enough to _just_ run the appropriate part of the `UNION`. You'd have to check the query plan to be sure.

Comment: Hi Ann, I have tried this but unfortunately it is not giving the exact result. I am not sure why. But even this is a big troublemaker that this logic is not giving the expected result :(

Comment: Hi, @Arnav.  Is it possible that `A.field1` may sometimes be null?  That would cause records to drop out.

Comment: @Arnav Do you think too many records are being returned, or too few?

Comment: @AnnL. The number is too few. That's my concern. Does a left outer join outside the query change something. And if yes, then how can it be shortened.

Comment: @Arnav Do you mean that you're taking this query and doing a left outer join from it to something else?  On what fields? Are you doing any filtering (a WHERE or HAVING clause) on this new, outer query?

Comment: @Arnav Just noticed I made a typo in my final query in my solution.  I will fix it. The final WHERE clause should check `A.field1` in both cases, not `field1` and `field2`.